# openbox - disable window move to another desktop workspace

Tags: openbox

I have a openbox configuration where I have two desktop workspaces. If I open a window in desktop 1 I would like to have the option to disable the move of that window from desktop 1 to desktop 2; the same can be stated for desktop 2, disabling the option of moving a window opened in desktop 2 to desktop 1.
Is this possible? If so, how could that be configured?
EDIT: To elaborate a little more. There is the ability, currently, to grab the Title bar of a window (cursor changes to a hand), then the keyboard shortcut of Window/Superkey+F1 or F2 will move that window to the other desktop workspace. This is what I need to disable.
Thanks.

Comment: I've been testing more and it looks as if that function is a default. I would like to change that default, if it is possible.